# Did they ever return for 'The Book'

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, ancient-races

In the **Stargate SG-1**, S1 episode [The Torment of Tantalus](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Torment_of_Tantalus), they gate to a planet which had an ancient meeting place of The Four Great Races.

The races had there some compendium of knowledge, which Daniel figured had to be worth a LOT of scientific interest.

At the end of the episode, they try dialing back to the planet, but cannot get through, presumably because the gate has fallen into the ocean.

Once the SGC had access to space craft, is there any indication of them having ever made a visit back to this planet, to try to recover the database of The Book?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Canonically, there's no mention of the team attempting to physically fly to the destination gate. We do know that the castle was on the verge of collapsing and the fact that the gate was buried gives an strong indication that it's fallen into the sea or under tonnes of rubble.

[image: Tantalus Castle]

Ultimately they don't really need to return anyway because they have Ernest Littlefield's comprehensive notes about the book and the information contained within.

> **DAVIS:** *Chevrons 6 encoded. (We see, Daniel, Ernest, Jack and Cat all watching.) Chevron seven...will not engage.*
>
> **O'NEILL:** *Well, I think it is safe to say that, that place is gone.*
>
> **EARNEST:** *You still have my book.*
>
> **CATHERINE:** *Captain Carter is working a computer model right now.*
>
> **AIRMAN:** *Go to reactor seven.*
>
> **O'NEILL:** *And here's the bright side; you alive.*
>
> **DANIEL:** *Yes. (Danny looks at Ernest.) Thanks to you.*
>
> **EARNEST:** *Look at it this way, if you ever run into those aliens, that made up the language, you can ask them what it means.*

[image: Tantalus Book]

Comment: Good answer. The last quote also implies that they never returned to Heliopolis: SG-1 went on to establish extremely good relations with the Asgard.

Comment: Well, even in his whole lifetime that he was there, I'm sure Earnest wouldn't have been able to get down even a fraction of what the compendium contained... but I will accept that most of it could probably have been gotten from the Asgard.